# How should I use this voltage regulator for best efficiency?

Tags: pcb, voltage-regulator, low-power

I want to design a low power battery powered PCB. My battery has a voltage of 3.6V. Suppose there are 3 ICs in the circuit and one of them is powered with a max 3.3V.

Power loss of voltage regulator is (Vi-Vo)xI.

So the more ICs I connect to the output of the VR, the higher loss will be. Is this true? If there is an IC in the circuit running in the 3-5V range, would it be better to power it directly from the battery? It makes more sense to connect the output of the voltage regulator only to the IC operating at a maximum voltage of 3.3V. I'm confused at this point. How should the voltage regulator be used correctly? What features of the voltage regulator should I pay attention to for lower power consumption?

Comment: Your assumptions seem to assume a linear regulator. And powering chips at different voltages is possible but then communication between them also happens at different voltages which then will be a new problem to solve. We don't know what chips you have and how you want to connect them so the question can't be answered without more info.

Comment: I want to supply the STM32L073 with 3.6V, the MFRC630 with 3.6V and the E19-868MS100 with 3.3V. But I can replace these ICs later. That's why I didn't specify a specific model.

Comment: You need to add relevant information to the question, not supply it in the comments.

Comment: What battery you have that is 3.6V? Lithium, NiMH, lead-acid? Is it nominal 3.6V or max 3.6V?

Comment: @Justme 3.6V 9000mAh Lithium battery

Comment: @harmonica Then your question is invalid. Lithium battery is 3.6V on average. When fully charged, it has about 4.2V. You can't connect chips with up to 3.6V max operating voltage to a fully charged battery with 4.2V.

Comment: @Justme I don't think what you're saying is always true. I used several fully charged lithium batteries and they all had a voltage of 3.6V. They fed ICs without problems.

Comment: @harmonica Lithium battery 3.6V is nominal. It will be roughly 4.2V when full and about 3.0V when empty. A battery can't be fully charged if it has 3.6V, it would maybe be have about 10% of charge.

Comment: 3.6v is nearly discharged for a typical lithium ion battery. Regardless it sounds like you might be better with a switching regulator than a linear one.

Comment: @Justme Actually, the question I asked is completely related to the linear voltage regulator. I don't see any reason to mention the battery issue. All the batteries I have are 3.6V lithium batteries and I have no problem with the battery. But thanks for the extra info anyway.

Comment: @justme, it's possible the OP is referring to a 3.6v lithium *primary* battery, not a lithium-ion/poly rechargeable battery.

Comment: I think you have an issue regardless. If the batteries only have max 3.6V then they are charged wrong. And if you put a simple 3.3V linear regulator, and feed it from batteries that get drained, the regulator needs some overhead to work. So when the battery output voltage drops enough the regulator can't give out 3.3V any more and it starts dropping too.

Comment: @Justme It may also be a LiFePO4 cell, fully charged at 3.6V

Answer (score 1):

Assuming linear regulator.

> What features of the voltage regulator should I pay attention to for lower power consumption?

Quiescent current, obviously, including feedback resistors. That pretty much means a PMOS LDO, because the base current in a PNP LDO isn't free.

Dropout voltage, because the device will run until the battery is discharged to the minimum voltage your device needs plus the LDO dropout. So, if your battery is Lithium (say 3.0-4.2V) and your micro runs down to 3.0V, a lower dropout means longer battery life. Although there's not much energy left at the end of the discharge. Note what matters is the dropout voltage at the current your device is actually using when it runs.

Transient response, because you don't want the regulator to be too slow to wake up when the micro comes out of sleep. That can cause a voltage sag and then a reboot. Problem is, low quiescent LDOs tend to be slow, so there's a compromise to make here between quiescent current, speed, and capacitors on the output.

> So the more ICs I connect to the output of the VR, the higher loss will be. Is this true? If there is an IC in the circuit running in the 3-5V range, would it be better to power it directly from the battery?

It depends on what the load is.

If it's a constant power load, like a switching LED driver, it will waste less power  if it is supplied directly from the battery. If a lower supply voltage is used, it will draw more current to compensate.

If it's a constant current load, like an opamp idling, then it doesn't matter if the extra power is dissipated in the opamp or the LDO. So, your choice.

If it's a load whose current depends on voltage, like a microcontroller, then with lower voltage it will use less current, so that may be an advantage.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need an exact regulated supply, you can put a schottky diode between battery and the common board supply. If the MCU is aware of the battery voltage, it can bypass the diode with a P MOSFET when the battery is below 3.3V. However, this only works if the minimum current is high enough to produce the voltage drop and the diode temperature is moderate.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhd6Lj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>